# how to convert a csv to xml through XSLT file using Java code and Saxon-HE Saxon-HE-9.5.1-5

Tags: xslt, csv, saxon

I'm trying to translate this command line code (which takes a .csv file and converts to xml through an xslt file and this works) to Java code:
java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:"csv2xml.xslt" flatfile=input.csv -s:dummy.xml > output.txt

//Java Code using Saxon-HE 9.5:
public static void transformFileUsingStyleSheet(String csvFile, String xslID)
            throws TransformerException {

```
    // Create a transform factory instance.
    TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
    Transformer transformer =
        tfactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslID));

    // Transform the source XML to System.out.
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(csvFile),
                          new StreamResult(new File("ConvertedCSV2XML.xml")));

}
```

But I'm getting this error when calling the above java method:  **SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog** like this: transformFileUsingStyleSheet("input.csv","csv2xml.xslt.xslt");

Comment: The file you're transforming must be well-formed XML. What I would do is pass the XSLT file itself as input (or still use `dummy.xml`) and the CSV as an `xsl:param`. You can read the CSV for processing with `unparsed-text()`. (That's what appears to be happening anyway based on the command line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line you have posted suggests that the Xslt takes a parameter named `flatfile` you have to set before running the transformation so make sure you do that in your Java code as well, should be `transformer.setParameter("flatfile", csvFile)`. And as already pointed out in a comment, the command lines passes in a dummy.xml Xml input document, if you want to use the Transformer API you need to do this as well so make sure you pass in a third parameter `inputFile` with e.g. `dummy.xml` and then use `transformer.transform(new StreamSource(inputFile), ..)` as the first argument to the transform method.

However, note that Saxon has its own Api that allows you to run a stylesheet starting with a named template without needing a dummy XML input file.

Comment: Thank you what you suggested worked! Just curious how would I do this with the Saxon API wihout using the dummy XML input file?

Comment: See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation for an overview of using that API, once you have an `XsltTransformer`, you can do `xsltTransformerInstance.setInitialTemplate(new QName("main"))` to set a template named `main` as the starting point. In the stylesheet you would then have e.g. `<xsl:template match="/" name="main">...</xsl:template>`. Then set the parameter `xsltTransformerInstance.setParameter(new QName("flatfile"), new XdmAtomicValue(csvFile))`.

Answer (score 0):

The JAXP transformation API is designed for XSLT 1.0, which requires an XML document as the principal source document. You will either need to supply a dummy source document (XML) to satisfy the API, or use Saxon's s9api API which gives full access to XSLT 2.0 (and XSLT 3.0) capabilities.

Comment: Thank you, how would I go about using Saxon's s9api and convert the Java code I posted?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation (http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation) for a quick intro, or if you like working from examples, download the saxon-resources file at http://saxonica.com/download/saxon-resources9-5.zip and look for the S9APIExamples.java module.